# Display the value in sonata admin list

Tags: mongodb, symfony

in my mongo the collection is like this

```
<?php

namespace Shiran\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="user_feedback")
 */
class User {

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="userId", type="int")
 * @MongoDB\Index(unique=true)
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="message", type="string")
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="created", type="date")
 */
private $created;

public function __construct() {
    $this->created = new \MongoDate(time());
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUser() {
    return $this->userId;
}
public function getMessage(){
    return $this->message;
}

public function getCreated() {
    return $this->created;
}
public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function setUser($user){
    $this->userId = $user;
}
public function setMessage($message){
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function setCreated($created) {
    $this->created = $created;
}
  }

?>
```

and when i want to display the value in the sonata admin list all the field was display expect userId

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('message')
        ->add('created')    
        ->add('userId')

        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'view' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

my mongo data collection is store like this

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("53719e0841a0a13f0d8b4567"),
 "userId": NumberInt(332273),
 "message": "Your feed back",
 "created": ISODate("2014-05-13T04: 22: 32.0Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `getter` for the field you want to show. In your entity there is no function called `getUserId` .

Try using `->add('user')` as there is a method `getUser` and returns the userId